# After adding a sticky column to an Angular Material Table, the table row's mouse over functionality has broken

Tags: angular, angular-material

The sticky cell's box shadow is not visible when a table row is moused over.

```html
.mat-row:hover {
    background: #d00e0eec;
    height: 2.125rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) !important;
    position: relative;
}
```

ID and Project Name is sticky column.

How to get to **box-shadow** ?
[image]

**EDIT 1**:
Here I'm using **Angular Material table**.
I made the row position **relative** because I couldn't apply a box shadow to the table row. After that, the *box shadow appeared*.

Now I wanted to make the first column *sticky*, so I did.
Now that the sticky column has been added, **now box shadow doesn't appears on sticky column rows.**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below css to table element.

```
.mat-table {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Comment: I need box-shadow for sticky columns

Answer (score 0):

Made quick snippet and it seems to work fine, can you post your html code as well and more of your CSS

or try with(apply the below css only to the desired row)

```
.mat-row {
border-spacing: 6px; 
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 20rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  height: 5rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}


.fixed-top {
background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fixed-top:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="fixed-top">ID</th>
        <th class="fixed-top">Project Name</th>
        <th class="fixed-top">gory</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td class="observed-row">1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>test </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>test 4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>test 5</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Ivilin, Thanks for the suggestion but I'm trying for the Angular material table

Comment: alright, I edit my answer with another suggestion, let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks,
But I figured out the issue was with the position
Now after adding the z index to the relative position it's working thanks